# CentOS VM with Bridged Network Vhosts Can't Be Accessed

Tags: macos, networking, centos, virtualbox, vhosts

I’ve created a VM (with VirtualBox) of CentOS on my MacBook Pro with the ethernet set to Bridged. So, the VM has its own static IP address of 192.168.1.111

Within the “hosts” file on the VM, I’ve got:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.example.com
```

Within the “hosts” file on my MacBook Pro (the host machine), I’ve got:

```
192.168.1.111 dev.example.com
```

Now the site works fine from within the VM, but doesn’t pull up anything from the host MacBook Pro…

I’ve spent literally 2 days trying to setup this network and I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: I don't know much about macbooks and the software present on them, but surely I know some networking stuff, it would be helpful if you could provide more details about what software you are using to manage VMs? Something like VirtualBox, etc?

Comment: Check if the Virtual Ethernet Card you are using with vbox enabled and configured inside the VM?

Comment: I can access Google from within the VM. So yes, it's enabled and configured.

Comment: Figured it out. CentOS firewall wasn't allowing incoming HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the CentOS Firewall. It wasn't allowing incoming HTTP requests. Had nothing to do with my hosts files.